# IN and OUT instructions

Tags: assembly, io, x86, hardware

i just want to make sure that i got that right.

when i use the IN and OUT instructions in x86.

the CPU sends the port address to the right I/O controller, how does it know which one is the right one ? it knows by looking up the I/O address space, which basically contain a range of port addresses that correspond to an I/O controller.

so let's say the port addresses **0x1000-0x2000** are for the "disk controller"

and the port address **0x3000-0x4000** are for "network controller"

if i send the port address 0x1003 then the cpu will send the port address to the "disk controller".

then the I/O controller receives that port address it then looks up it's internal mapping table in it's memory to determine what register(could also be a memory) of the I/O device is associated with that port address.

then it request to read or write(depends on the instruction) to one of these I/O device registers.

Comment: Logically at least, all devices listen for all ports, and only respond to certain ports.  So the CPU doesn't have to know what device will respond before it sends a message on the external bus, that's why there's only I/O address space shared by all devices.  On really ancient systems like 8086, there was only one external bus for memory and I/O, with one control line to indicate if it was an I/O or a memory access.  On modern systems with PCIe, something probably does have to figure out where to send a request since it's not a shared bus, it's point-to-point links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i send the port address 0x1003 then the cpu will send the port address to the "disk controller".

Your idea how `in` and `out` work is not completely correct:

I don't know about modern CPUs, but using a simpler CPU (such as the 80386) `in` and `out` are variants of the `mov` instruction accessing different addresses:

If you see the `M/IO` pin just as an additional address wire, addresses are 33-bit values, not 32-bit values.

The instruction `out dx, al` does exactly the same as a `mov [edx], al` instruction with only one difference: `out dx, al` writes to the (33-bit) address `[0x100000000+dx]` while `mov [edx], al` writes to the address `[edx]`.

Now what does the CPU do in this case?

The CPU uses 33 wires (the address bus) to send the address and 8 wires (the data bus) to send the value of `al`. It uses additional wires to send the information that some 8-bit value is being written.

There is some circuit **outside** the CPU that checks which address is which device:

This circuit "knows" that addresses `0...0x9FFFF` are RAM and when you write to one of these addresses (e.g. you write to address `0x1234` using `mov [0x1234],al`), the circuit sends an electrical signal to the RAM.

If you write to address `0x100001234` (e.g. using `out dx, al` with `dx=0x1234`), the circuit sends some signal to the disk controller (in your example).

Let's say the disk controller uses only addresses `0x1000...0x10FF` (actually: `0x100001000...0x1000010FF`).

In this case, the disk controller will typically only use the low 8 bits of the address and ignore the other address bits. So if you write to address `dx=0x11FF`, this has the same effect as writing to address `dx=0x10FF`.

In this case, only 8 of the 33 signals holding the address coming from the CPU need to be connected to the disk controller.

The disk controller receives the following signals:

- The 8 signals containing the value of `al` (from the CPU)
- The 8 low bits of the address being accessed (from the CPU)
- The signals saying that an 8-bit value is being written (from the CPU)
- The signal saying that the disk controller is being accessed (from the circuit outside the CPU)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that it was implemented by setting a 33rd bit.

Comment: @puppydrum64 Officially, the `M/IO` pin is a "control pin" and not an "address pin". However, actually it is nothing but a 33rd address pin.